# converting style1.css, style2.css ... and put the content into <style>...</style>

Tags: php, css, minify

Let's say I have:
css/style1.css
css/style2.css...
etc

and the html is like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<link ... src="css/style1.css">
<link ... src="css/style2.css">
</head>
<body>...</body>
</html>
```

I would like to read all the contents of css and make it like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>...(all css styles go here)</style>
</head>
<body>...</body>
</html>
```

reading css and put it into  is easy (ie. using php's file_get_contents) but if the css contains url (url(../images/something.png)) or @import then it would be difficult.

I know there are some tools like minify css (https://github.com/mrclay/minify) to read multiple css and combine them into a big one, but still, it's not exactly what I want (what I want is all styles have to be inside

so is there any tool / script that can do this easily?

Comment: I assume you have no way of cleaning the files of relative asset paths and import statements? That does complicate things.

Comment: It sounds like you already have your tools:  one to combine the files and one to take the contents and put them in your document like you want.  Is there something that's preventing you from using them together?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If it's to resolve caching issues, there are [better](http://css-tricks.com/can-we-prevent-css-caching/) [ways](http://css-tricks.com/update-on-css-caching/). Caching is good, you shouldn't break it.

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
<style type="text/css">
  @import url("style1.css");
  @import url "style2.css";
</style>
```

OR

```
<style type="text/css">
  @import url("style1.css");
  p { color : #f00; }
</style>
```

http://webdesign.about.com/cs/css/qt/tipcssatimport.htm

OR

make `main`  `CSS` File and paste below code in `main css` file

```
@import url('style1.css');
@import url('style2.css');
@import url('style3.css');
@import url('style4.css');
```

add in head below source code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="main.css"></link>
```

Comment: I don't think this is relevant to his question. If I'm not mistaking he wants to get the content of two `.css` files that are linked with `<link>` tag and he wants to get the content of those files and place them as embedded styles inside `<style>` tags in place of the two `<link>` elements directly on his markup.

Comment: I can't use @import what I really want is to get all the contents from the css files and parse them into <style> tag

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    @import url('css/style1.css');
    @import url('css/style2.css');
</style>
</head>
<body>...</body>
</html>
```

Comment: not really what I want. the exact contents has to be inside <style></style>, not just some links like @import

Answer (score 0):

You are using php so you can do something like this to get your css.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <style type='text/css'>
   <?php
     $css = file_get_contents('path/to/style1.css'); //get your css contents
     echo $css; //paste your css
   ?>
  </style>      
 </head>
</html>
```

Comment: please read my question carefully. I already knew how to use file_get_contents. It's just you can't echo the css directly without modifying the url. ie. url(../images/images.png) or @import